# Transversality in $2$-manifold

Tags: differential-topology, transversality

Let $X, Y$ be $2$-dimensional smooth manifolds without boundary, and $P$ be a disconnected $1$-dimensional boundaryless embedded submanifold of $Y$. Let $f\colon X\to Y$ be a smooth map that is transverse to $P$. So, $f^{-1}(P)$ is a $1$-dimensional boundaryless embedded submanifold of $X$.

> Let $C$ be a component of $P$ and $C'$ be a component of $f^{-1}(C)$.
> Is $f\big |C'\to C$ a submersion?

**My attempt:** $f$ is transverse to $P$ implies $f$ is transverse to $C$ from definition.

Let $x\in C'$. So, $T_x(C')=T_x\big(f^{-1}(C)\big)=df_x^{-1}\big(T_{f(x)}(C)\big)$.  The first equality is due to connectedness and the last equality due to transversality.

Therefore, $df_x\big(T_x(C')\big)=df_x\big(df_x^{-1}\big(T_{f(x)}(C)\big)\big)\subseteq T_{f(x)}(C)$.

Since $T_{f(x)}(C)$ is of $1$-dimensional vector space, the vector subspace $df_x\big(T_x(C')\big)$ can be either $0$ or $1$-dimensional.

Now, I have to show $df_x\big(T_x(C')\big)=T_{f(x)}(C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Counterexample: $X = Y = \mathbb R^2$, $P = x$-axis and
$$f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2, \ \ \ f(x, y) = (x^3, y).$$

Then $f$ is transverse to $P$, $f^{-1} (P) = x$-axis, but

$$f|_{f^{-1}\ (P)} (x, 0) = (x^3, 0)$$
is not a submersion.